# Acknowledgement.acknowledge() Null point exception

Tags: spring-kafka

I have closed auto commit, set `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, but it also produces null point exception

[image]

[image]

This is the exception:

```
(java.util.List<org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1311) [spring-kafka-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

2.2.x is no longer supported, and 2.2.5 is 2 1/2 years old.

See the [project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) for supported versions.

That was a bug in 2.2.5 - it implies that some code threw a `ListenerExecutionFailedException` with no cause; I don't see that happening in framework code (but I haven't looked extensively), perhaps your code is throwing it?

When reporting problems like this, you must show code, configuration, logs and the full stack trace.

Try upgrading to a supported version - 2.3.14, 2.5.15, 2.6.10, or 2.7.6 - the newer the better.